# CR in VS2012 using C#.net desktop application

Tags: c#-4.0

while using SAP CR in VS2012 , problem is occurred while choose datasource of crystal report viewer and the error message is "An error occurred while adding a Strongly- Typed ReportDocument. The report may be corrupt or invalid."

Answer (score 1):

Try to load the report using ReportDocument.Load method. This will allow you to work with the reports without adding them to the project and also will allow you to see the full error during runtime